# PHP SoapClient with SuperPages API

Tags: php, api, soap, soap-client

So I'm completely new to SOAP and the whole idea behind it, but I am forced to figure it out in order to work with the SuperPages API. For now, I am just trying to wrap my head around it, and how to make calls to the API. The API documentation can be found here: http://advertising.superpages.com/spapiweb/v2. I am able to login via the headers, but I can't quite figure out where to go from there. Here is documentation for the function I'm attempting to run:

```
getReportList
```

The getReportList method retrieves a list of the reports that are currently stored.

Request:

```
Field Name             Field Type  Field Description    Field
externalTransactionId   string(6)   External Transaction identifier used for logging. Provided by user. Optional
```

Response

```
<soap:Envelope 
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <ns2:getReportListResponse xmlns:ns2="webobjects.reporting.pbap.spmd.com">
     <return>
        <ns2:report>
           <ns2:reportName></ns2:reportName>
           <ns2:reportId></ns2:reportId>
           <ns2:reportType></ns2:reportType>
           <ns2:status></ns2:status>
           <ns2:startDate></ns2:startDate>
           <ns2:endDate></ns2:endDate>
           <ns2:createdDate></ns2:createdDate>
        </ns2:report>
        <ns2:totalRows></ns2:totalRows>
        <ns2:dateCreated></ns2:dateCreated>
        <ns2:internalTransactionId></ns2:internalTransactionId>
     </return>
  </ns2:getReportListResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

My code:

```
 $options = array('trace' => true);
 $sp = new SoapClient('http://services.superpages.com/spexternalservicesv3/services/reportingservice?wsdl', $options);
 $header = new SoapHeader('[companyId]', '[username]', '[password]');
 $sp->__setSoapHeaders($header);

 echo "<pre>";
 var_dump($sp->__getFunctions()); //check that I'm at least doing something right
 echo "</pre>";

 $sp->__soapCall("getReportList",array("")); //empty array, because parameter is optional in documentation
```

My results:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(59) "getReportURLResponse getReportURL(getReportURL $parameters)"
  [1]=>
  string(83) "scheduleAgencyReportResponse scheduleAgencyReport(scheduleAgencyReport $parameters)"
  [2]=>
  string(65) "scheduleReportResponse scheduleReport(scheduleReport $parameters)"
  [3]=>
  string(59) "deleteReportResponse deleteReport(deleteReport $parameters)"
  [4]=>
  string(62) "getReportListResponse getReportList(getReportList $parameters)"
}


Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap:Client] Error reading XMLStreamReader. in /home/a2op/public_html/billing/sp/index.php:11 Stack trace: #0 /home/a2op/public_html/billing/sp/index.php(11): SoapClient->__soapCall('getReportList', Array) #1 {main} thrown in /home/a2op/public_html/billing/sp/index.php on line 11
```

What am I doing wrong here?

---

### EDIT

When debugging via

```
try {
    var_dump($sp->getReportList());
} catch (SoapFault $exception) {
    var_dump($exception->getMessage());
    var_dump($exception);
}
```

, this is the error dump

```
string(32) "Fault occurred while processing."
object(SoapFault)#5 (8) {
  ["message:protected"]=>
  string(32) "Fault occurred while processing."
  ["string:private"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["code:protected"]=>
  int(0)
  ["file:protected"]=>
  string(43) "/home/a2op/public_html/billing/sp/index.php"
  ["line:protected"]=>
  int(19)
  ["trace:private"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(6) {
      ["file"]=>
      string(43) "/home/a2op/public_html/billing/sp/index.php"
      ["line"]=>
      int(19)
      ["function"]=>
      string(6) "__call"
      ["class"]=>
      string(10) "SoapClient"
      ["type"]=>
      string(2) "->"
      ["args"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(13) "getReportList"
        [1]=>
        array(0) {
        }
      }
    }
    [1]=>
    array(6) {
      ["file"]=>
      string(43) "/home/a2op/public_html/billing/sp/index.php"
      ["line"]=>
      int(19)
      ["function"]=>
      string(13) "getReportList"
      ["class"]=>
      string(10) "SoapClient"
      ["type"]=>
      string(2) "->"
      ["args"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
    }
  }
  ["faultstring"]=>
  string(32) "Fault occurred while processing."
  ["faultcode"]=>
  string(11) "soap:Server"
}
```

---

### EDIT

XML output after running

```
try{
    var_dump($sp->getReportList());
}catch (SoapFault $exception) {
    var_dump($exception->getMessage());
    var_dump($exception);
}
echo $sp->__getLastRequest();
```

--

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
  xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:ns1="webobjects.reporting.pbap.spmd.com">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <ns1:username>[username]</ns1:username>
    <ns1:password>[password]</ns1:password>
    <ns1:companyId>[companyId]</ns1:companyId>
  </SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:getReportList/>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting: never used it before, but I think that this is wrong:

```
$header = new SoapHeader('[companyId]', '[username]', '[password]');
$sp->__setSoapHeaders($header);
```

I think you want this:

```
$headers = array();
$header[] = new SoapHeader('webobjects.reporting.pbap.spmd.com', 'username', '[username]');
$header[] = new SoapHeader('webobjects.reporting.pbap.spmd.com', 'password', '[password]');
$header[] = new SoapHeader('webobjects.reporting.pbap.spmd.com', 'companyId', '[companyId]');
$sp->__setSoapHeaders($headers);
```

see http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.setsoapheaders.php for the `setSoapHeaders()` multiple header call and you should probably dump out the request XML to verify that it looks like the example at http://advertising.superpages.com/spapiweb/v2?wicket:interface=:11:3: .

Let me know if it works.

Comment: I tried doing the headers the way you suggested. This did not cause an error, nor did it change anything. When I try to run __getLastResponse, __getLastResponseHeaders, __getLastRequest and __getLastRequestHeaders, they all return null. Is it a false assumption that since _getFunctions() is working that I am "logging in" correctly?

Comment: `__getFunctions` will probably work fine regardless: my expectation is that it comes from the WSDL, which doesn't require you to log in. You said there were no errors thrown (so that's at least something) but you're invoking the method wrong. All you should need to do is `$sp->getReportList();`: SoapClient does the function call translation and invokes the correct SOAP function for you. Try that and let me know what it says.

Comment: Hm... I tried `$sp->getReportList();` and got this error: `Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap:Server] Fault occurred while processing. in /home/a2op/public_html/billing/sp/index.php:14 Stack trace: #0 /home/a2op/public_html/billing/sp/index.php(14): SoapClient->__call('getReportList', Array) #1 /home/a2op/public_html/billing/sp/index.php(14): SoapClient->getReportList() #2 {main} thrown in /home/a2op/public_html/billing/sp/index.php on line 14`

Comment: In addition, I tried running `var_dump(method_exists($sp,'getReportList'));` , which returned false.

Comment: `method_exists` won't work; neither will `is_callable`, as the method translation is done inside the SoapClient object's `__call` function. You should catch the error like so: `try{ $sp->getReportList(); }catch (SoapFault $exception){ var_dump($exception->getMessage); }` and see what the exception message is.

Comment: odd..does `try{ var_dump($sp->getReportList()); }catch (SoapFault $exception){ var_dump($exception->getMessage());var_dump($exception); }` also return NULL;

Comment: That returns a SoapFault object. Too much to paste, but the message is "Fault occurred while processing."

Comment: Edit your question and add the output: it'll be hard to help figure out what's going wrong without looking at the dump.

Comment: Done. I really appreciate all the help Femi, I've been tearing my hear out trying to figure this thing out!

Comment: I see. Try this: try{ var_dump($sp->getReportList()); }catch (SoapFault $exception){ var_dump($exception->getMessage());var_dump($exception); } echo $sp->__getLastRequest();` and see if the XML output looks anything like the XML example at http://advertising.superpages.com/spapiweb/v2?wicket:interface=:3:1:#getreportlist

Comment: I ran the test and posted the XML at the end of my original question. It looks similar, but not quite there.

Comment: Well, it looks correct. Do you have valid and correct username/password/companyId values, and did you put those in `setHeader` calls? I would say you have an authorization error and need to verify that you have the correct username/password/companyId, so you might need to check with your superpages technical contact to get past that.

Comment: All of the header values are correct, I have also verified this with the SuperPages API support. Unfortunately, they do not provide any coding support. I am stumped, any other ideas?